# ALTER SYSTEM DISCONNECT SESSION doesn't work

Tags: oracle, oracle-11g

Oracle 11g. The devs leave sessions connected overnight, sometimes certain cron jobs fail because of that. I am trying to kill all user sessions, but I can't.

I login as:

```
sqlplus system/[password] as sysdba
```

I do this to list the sessions:

```
select sid,serial#,program from gv$session where type='USER' and machine!='this-server';
```

And the list looks like this:

```
       SID    SERIAL# PROGRAM
```

---

```
10   7883 toad.exe
11  42365 toad.exe
77  22493 toad.exe
```

Then I do:

```
alter system disconnect session '10,7883' immediate;
```

And is says:

```
System altered.
```

But nothing happens. The session is still there. What am I doing wrong?

P.S.: I'm pretty new to Oracle, I only used MySQL before.

Comment: Are you running RAC? Linux or Windows as the DB box?

Comment: I may as well also mention that if developers are leaving locks on a production system that cause things to fail - well, you need to fix the access they have and create a pre-production environment.

Comment: No RAC, Linux OS. This is a pre-prod environment, and educating the users is out of question. :)

Comment: "The session is still there" meaning stuff is still *locked*? Sessions [might 'hang around'](http://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:4974573906087#10661495292489) but the locks should not.

Answer (score 3):

If even an `ALTER SYSTEM KILL...` does not remove the session after a bit, then the only thing you are left with is to kill it on the OS level.  In Linux you can get the command to kill the process as follows:

```
SELECT 'kill ' || ' -9 ' || p.spid 
FROM v$session s
JOIN v$process p ON s.paddr = p.addr 
WHERE s.sid=:SID_To_Kill;
```

In Windows you can get the command to kill the thread as follows:

```
SELECT 'orakill ' || sys_context('USERENV', 'DB_NAME') || ' ' || p.spid 
FROM v$session s 
JOIN v$process p ON s.paddr = p.addr 
WHERE s.sid=:SID_To_Kill;
```

It might be simpler just to have cron bounce the database before running the jobs.

Answer (score 1):

You should probably be using "Alter system KILL session 'sid,serial';" Disconnect should be a clean disconnect, but sounds like you need the kill.

Comment: KILL doesn't work either.

Answer (score 0):

We've seen zombie connections survive after the client PC is rebooted, even powered off.  Oracle DB is 11G, running on RHEL5.  If the session was holding a lock, the lock stays in place until the database is rebooted or the Unix thread is killed.  It seems to be a bug in Ora 11G.